# Is there any way to check for syntax error for .vue file's template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Quite embarrassingly, I made a mistake in a template section of the vue file. I wrote v-for as following.

```
<template>
    <ul v-for="{data, key} in json_data" :key="key">
        <!-- some list related -->
    </ul>
</template>
```

Basically I used curly braces instead of paranthesis.

However, as a novice javascript / vue.js / nuxt.js developer, I did not catch this for a long time. For the longest time, I thought I was doing something wrong in the script section of the code. I was wondering why `data` and `key` were returning undefined.

As I code more and more, those silly syntax error may go away. But is there any training wheel that can be used to catch those error?

Comment: What IDE are you using? For example if you're using VSCode you can use the [Vetur extension](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur) to perform syntax highlighting and checking.

Comment: I am using VSCode with Vetur. While it helps tremendously with scripting section, the error like this in the template were not found :(

Comment: That's weird. I'm actually getting it: https://i.imgur.com/UA5cOmI.png Are you using single file Vue components?

Comment: That is definitely weird! My Vetur did not do that for me. https://imgur.com/a/vI4ipqG I am using single file Vue component.

Comment: @Terry do you happen to use any kind of linting such as eslint?

Comment: I have VueCLI set up so yeah, I am using eslint.

Comment: When you hover over the red line, you should see some sort of description (if it is eslint, it would describe what it is warning/erroring us about) Would you mind showing me what it saids? Also, I learned a bit more about eslintrc.js. What extends and rules do you have?

Answer (score -1):

i assume that you are using vue.js in production mode.
you should use the vue.js library in developer's mode during development, this mode will display for you in the console a lot of details about your exceptions and errors.

here is the cdn:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

i also suggest that you use vue.js developer tools extension on your browser
here is the link for this extension

```html
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd
```

Comment: I am running nuxt.js with dev mode via "npm run dev" and I do have the vuejs-devtools